# How to get correct position on ties in mysql rankings

Tags: mysql, ranking

This is my code and works for ties but it does not skip position on ties

```
SELECT   `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
         @rank_count := @rank_count + (totalrate/nrrates < @prev_value) rank,
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     table, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
 ORDER BY avg DESC
```

Here is the out I get

```
item        (`totalrate` / `nrrates`)    rank     avg

Virginia        10.0000                    1      10
Ana             9.7500                     2      9.75
Angeie          9.72                       3      9.72
Carel           9.666666666                4      9.66
sammy           9.666666666                4      9.66
Oda             9.500000000                5      9.5
```

I want

```
item        (`totalrate` / `nrrates`)    rank     avg

Virginia        10.0000                    1      10
Ana             9.7500                     2      9.75
Angeie          9.72                       3      9.72
Carel           9.666666666                4      9.66
sammy           9.666666666                4      9.66
Oda             9.500000000                6      9.5
```

To skip the 5 position

I would like to merge with this that does skip position on ties

(I took the below code from this post
[MySQL Rank in the Case of Ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100010/mysql-rank-in-the-case-of-ties))

```
SELECT t1.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 t2 WHERE t2.score > t1.score) +1
AS rnk
FROM table_1 t1
```

how would I modify my code to get it to skip position with the above code it looks simple but i haven't figured it out.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a set of sample records and an expected output from the select.

Comment: I put the tables hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

On ties, you may want to skip and use current row num to next unmatched avg value row as next rank.
Following should help you

```
SELECT   `item`, @curr_avg := ( `totalrate` / `nrrates` )
       , case when @prev_avg = @curr_avg then @rank := @rank 
              else @rank := ( @cur_row + 1 )
          end as rank
       , @cur_row := ( @cur_row + 1 ) as cur_row 
       , @prev_value := @curr_avg avg
FROM     table
       , ( SELECT @prev_avg := 0, @curr_avg := 0
                , @rank := 0, @cur_row := 0 ) init
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

**Similar examples**:

- [To display top 4 rows using rank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949174/767881)
- [Mysql Query for Rank (RowNumber) and Groupings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23345218/767881)
- [Update a field with an incrementing value that resets based on
  field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23297536/767881)

Comment: I doesnt give me a 1-10 rank

Comment: What was the result? Can you post sample records from your table on http://sqlfiddle.com and let us know?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. First, the averages are calculated. If they are already available in a table, it would be even easier (as can be seen in the fiddle demo). Anyways, the rank is based on the logic of counting how many items have a lesser average than the current item.

```
SELECT
A1.`item`,
A1.avg,
COUNT(A2.`item`) avg_rank
FROM
(
SELECT   `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     table, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
) A1   --alias for the inline view
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT   `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     table, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
) A2   --alias for the inline view
ON A2.avg < A1.avg
GROUP BY A1.id, A1.avg
ORDER BY A1.avg;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e7252/10)</kbd>

Comment: can you tell me what A1 and A2 mean

Comment: A1 and A2 are the aliases that are given to the "inline views". Basically, they are the names which are used to refer to the columns inside the two sub-queries.

Comment: I have added comments in the two places where these aliases are defined. Then, they are used in the outer query.

Comment: Note that you shouln't use the fiddle out of the box as one of the values is missing. In this case the (10,0).